# Area of an arbitrarily oriented plane

Tags: vectors, area, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

How do I find the area of a plane, whose normal vector is given by
$$
a\overrightarrow{i}+b\overrightarrow{j}+c\overrightarrow{k}
$$
*a,b and c* are Real numbers.

I would have four 3-D coordinates which form this plane, and using these coordinates I will have to find out the area of the plane formed by the planes. I am writing code for this and will be required to perform this operation multiple times, so I am not inclined towards using the cross product

The initial idea that I had was to perform a series of rotations to transform the plane parallel to one of the *XY, YZ or ZX* planes. But I am not able to figure out the axes about which these have to be performed.

Comment: _four 3-D coordinates_ - Is is possible to specify these coordinates, because without any idea of numerical position (or the normal vector) there are technically "infinite" ways to define / anchor the area.

Comment: "area of the plane formed by the planes"? Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you mean the area of the quadrilateral bound by the 4 points? If you're writing code for it, what's wrong with writing code to calculate cross products?

Comment: Only normal vector is not enough. You need the equation of the plane. Now if you mean area of the plane in question bound by coordinate planes, then project the plane in xy plane and find area of the projection. Multiply by $\sqrt{1 + (\frac{a}{c})^2 + (\frac{b}{c})^2}$ to find the required area.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-2d-polygon this might be helpful!

Comment: @SnipingPoodle - So I will be required to calculate the Surface area of a ship. So the idea is to divide the surface into a number of planes and find the area of each of the plane. So the coordinates can literally be anything.

Comment: @user619894 and @ ConMan - Yes, it is the area of the quadrilateral formed by the 4 points. The problem is I will be required to perform this calculation large number of times to get the desired result which I mentioned before, so I wanted something faster. I am implementing this on MATLAB and there is a function for cross product. But my gut feeling is that it'll be slo

Comment: @MathLover Yeah, I am even looking at projection of this plane on individual planes. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Tutankhamun. Yeah I followed that thread when I was writing code for the area of a 2D quadrilateral. Now my objective is to find the area of a quadrilateral which is in the 3D space (the whole quadrilateral lying on some plane in the 3D space)

Comment: You can segment the quadrilateral into two triangles.  So if the four points are $A,B,C,D$, then segment it into $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ACD$.  Then find the areas of both triangles using cross product.  So that the area is $\frac{1}{2} ( | \vec{AB} \times \vec{AC} | + | \vec{AC} \times \vec{AD} | )$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have **4 completely different 3D points**, graphically the plane looks something like this: [image]

As seen in the image above the, the area is equal to $b \times h$, where $b$ = length between $C_2 \text{ and } C_3$, and $d$ = length between $C_3 \text{ and } C_4$.

For more complex shapes (shape of the plane), split them out into the basic shapes first, then continue with the method above. (Note: For triangles, Area = $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{ base } \times \text{ height }$): [image].

Hope this helps!